# How to merge arrays with sort in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Does anyone have an idea how to merge and sort array in PHP?
I have array "AAA". When I print:

```
Array
(
    [AAA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => c
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                )
        )
)
```

How can I merge this array to get result like:

```
Array
(
    [AAA] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: post your original array before you print that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, i have tried this code this is working as you expect.

**Example:-**

```
    <?php
    $array = array('AAA' => array(array('0' => "a",'1' => "b"), array('0' => "b")));

    //Before Sorting
   echo "Before sorting****".'<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';

    $my_array = array_merge($array['AAA'][0], $array['AAA'][1]);
    //After Sorting


     echo "After sorting****".'<pre>';
    print_r($my_array);
    echo '</pre>';

    ?>
```

Check Out the [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1ClwDB)

**Output:-**

```
Before sorting****

Array
(
    [AAA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                )

        )

)

After sorting****

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first merge using `array_merge` and then sort using `sort`

```
$temp = array_merge($arr['AAA'][0], $arr['AAA'][1]);
sort($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$l = iterator_to_array($it, false);

var_dump($l);
```